# How can I use Availability Panel in Calendar?

Tags: calendar

There is an item named `Availability Panel` in Calendar:

[image]

When I open it this message is shown:

> This calendar does not support availability.

What kinds of calendars are supported for calculating availability? I have personal calendars in Calendar with recurring events that none of them work with Availability Panel.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On BusyMac there is an [article](https://support.busymac.com/help/26212-free-busy-availability-viewer) about that. The Availability Panel is **supported by** e.g.:

- Exchange and Office 365
- Fruux
- OS X Calendar Server
- Kerio
- Zimbra

and **not supported by** e.g. iCloud, Google Calendar, Yahoo, Communigate, Beehive.

Comment: Google Calendar does support it. Might only be available to GSuite users. You may have to add and sync the child calendars to an iCloud account, that's when it started working for me